# Update active song position in windows phone by slider

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am building a music app in windows phone 8.1 silverlight. I used medialibrary and songcollection to access music library in device. I also use mediaplayer to play/pause/next/ song. But I want to use slider to change positon of active song but I have no idea to solve it. Please help me, thanks a lot!

```
private void changed_possition(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)//slider event 
    {
        if (MediaPlayer.State== MediaState.Playing)
        {
            TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, (int)music_slider.Value);
            MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Duration = ts;
        } 
    }
```

I try use this code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set the maximum of slider to

SliderMedia.Maximum = YourMediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;

and bind value of slider to

Value="{Binding ElementName=YourMediaElement,Path=Position.TotalSeconds,Mode=OneWay}"

Next, You can create ManipulationCompleted Event of slider as

long ticks = (long)(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * SliderMedia.Value);
YourMediaElement.Position = new TimeSpan(ticks);

With this ManipulationCompleted event, whenyou change the position of bar at slider, the position of your song will be changed.

Comment: Hi Shweta Goyal, first let me thanks for your support,but I used mediaplayer to play songs in MediaLibrary so what I should to do now ?

Comment: @NguyễnĐăngThế sorry for late response. If you are using media player then you simply have to assign the new position (changed) to BackgroundMediaplayer.Current.position

This will surely work